# Grouped bar charts with intersecting ticks

Tags: chart.js

I am currently working on a chart that shows 4 different datasets, two of them are represented by bars and the other 2 are represented by data points on those bars.

I am trying to show the "tick" marks on the bar where the data points represent the intersection of the data point with the bar data, however, the closest I can get to this is having 4 combo charts of 2 bar charts and 2 line charts with no line, and using a pointStyle of line. However, this isn't what the client is wanting or expecting.

I have tried multiple solutions to this (including using stacked bar charts with hidden borders, etc) to no effect.

I have attached a screenshot of what the current "solution" looks like. As you can see, the lines go across the entire category when they should just represent where they are on the bar (be it inside the bar or above it).

Is ChartJS capable of showing the point ON the bar chart that represents that data when its grouped like in the screenshot?

Current view:

[image]

What I would like to represent is what is shown (and circled below):
[image]

EDITED... added code to show what I'm currently doing (this is the closest I can get -- shortened version of what is being produced by top chart):

```
var chartData = {
            labels: ['Apr 2019', 'May 2019', 'Jun 2019'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Withdrawn',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                type: 'line',
                pointRadius: 10,
                pointHoverRadius: 15,
                showLine: false,
                data: [2543, 2501, 2401],
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
                pointStyle: 'line'
            },
            {
                label: 'Ongoing',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                type: 'line',
                pointRadius: 10,
                pointHoverRadius: 15,
                showLine: false,
                data: [1755, 2122, 2298],
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
                pointStyle: 'line'
            },
            {
                label: 'In Progress',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(94, 131, 186, 0.9)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(94, 131, 186, 0.9)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [2400, 2402, 2100],
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
            },
            {
                label: 'Cancelled',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(116, 162, 231, 0.9)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(116, 162, 231, 0.9)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [2410, 2222, 1704],
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
            }]                
        };

        var chart = new Chart(context, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartData,
            options: {
                layout: {
                    padding: {
                        top: 15
                    }
                },
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        position: 'left',
                        id: 'y-axis-1',
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 100
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code and the data to be shown in the chart to make it easier to others to suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was recommended to use float bars, which seems to have solved my problem.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
        labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        datasets: [
        {
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
            borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
            data: [10, 7, 9, 5, 8, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1],
            stack: '1'
        },
        {
           backgroundColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192, 0.5)",
           borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
           data: [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
           stack: '2'
        },
        {
           backgroundColor: 'black',
           data: [[11,11.1], [6,6.1]],
           stack: '1'
        },
        {
           backgroundColor: 'brown',
           data: [[9,9.1], [5,5.1]],
           stack: '2'
        }
        ]
   },
   options: {
       scales: {
           y: {
                stacked: false
           }
       }
   }
});
```

https://codepen.io/kurkle/pen/BaoQdLN?editors=1010